# Require/AMD and async resources in 2015

Tags: asynchronous, requirejs, amd

I'm building a library which uses asynchronous resources. I want the library to be loadable with AMD/require.

I've seen [this discussion](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/144) from 2011 about promises support, but it went nowhere.
I've seen plugins like [async](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins) and [require-promise](https://github.com/jokeyrhyme/requirejs-promise) - but I don't know how I feel about a library installing plugins.

I'm interested to know if anything has changed in terms of loading resources and/or dependent scripts. If promises are not supported, is there another way to signal requirejs that a script is ready in an asynchronous way?

Comment: [async](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins#plugins) requirejs plugin

Comment: @Vishwanath - I mentioned it in my question, is there a way do the same without a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I dived into the source of require.js, and I didn't find a way to make an asynchronous define. Plugins have the capability, but simple defines do not. I think the reason behind this is that async circular dependencies are a bit tricky.

However it is not impossible to write a mini async require-like library:

```
(function(context) {
  const modules = new Map();

  function require(name) {
    return Promise.resolve(null).then(function() {
      const module = modules.get(name);
      if (!module) throw new Error("Undefined module");
      if (module.promise) {
        return module.exports;
      } else {
        return module.promise = Promise.all(
            module.deps.map(internalRequire)
          ).then(function(args) {
            return module.factory.apply(context, args);
          }).then(function(defExport) {
            if (defExport !== undefined) {
              module.exports.default = defExport;
            }
            return module.exports;
          });
      }
      function internalRequire(name) {
        return (name === 'exports') ? module.exports : require(name);
      }
    });
  }

  function define(name, deps, factory) {
    if (modules.has(name)) throw new Error("Redefined module");
    modules.set(name, {
      name: name,
      deps: deps,
      factory: factory,
      exports: {},
      promise: null
    });
  }

  context.require = require;
  context.define = define;
})(self);
```

Usage:

```
define('A', ['B'], function(dep) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve("A(" + dep.default + ")");
        }, 100);
    });
});

define('B', ['C'], function(dep) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve("B(" + dep.default + ")");
        }, 100);
    });
});
define('C', ['A'], function(dep) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve("C(" + dep.default + ")");
        }, 100);
    });
});

require("A").then(function(s) {
    console.log(s);
});
```

Comment: as a library, I can't even consider replacing require-js, I wanted my library to be able to work with it.